# Не работает emmet в Visual Studio Code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

Хочу настроить Visual Studio Code для Web`a, но понял что у меня не работает плагин emmet. Перепробовал множество вариантов с Интернета, но мне ничего не помогло.

Мой settings.json:

```
{
    "workbench.sideBar.location": "left",
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "python.languageServer": "Microsoft",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [



        {
            "format": "expanded",
            "extensionName": ".css",
            "savePath": "css"
        }
    ],
    "emmet.excludeLanguages": [
    
        "html",
        "css",
        "markdown"
    ],
    "emmet.preferences": {


    },
    "emmet.showAbbreviationSuggestions": true,
    "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascript",
        "html": "html",
        "php": "html",
        "blade": "html",
    },
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
    "files.associations": {
    
    },
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": null
}
```

Comment: а который exention Вы установили?

Comment: Я установил Live Sass Compiler, Live Server, PHP IntelliSense, Python, GoLang Support, Eslint и ещё несколько которые не имеют отношения к emmet

Comment: Посмотрите на внимательно, я ниже указал что у вас в исключительных html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а ничего так у Вас одновременно

```
"emmet.excludeLanguages": [
    
        "html",
        "css",
        "markdown"
    ],

"emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascript",
        "html": "html",
        "php": "html",
        "blade": "html",
    },
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам. Я уже разобрался, просто переустановил Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 1):

в моем случае:

```
"files.associations": {"*html": "html"},
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
     "html": "html",
     "cshtml": "html",
     "razor": "html"
}
```

file.association помог мне

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык

Answer (score 1):

В setting > emmet > найти " Trigger Expansion On Tab" > поставь галочку